# When does a database link connection is established?

Tags: database, oracle, database-connection, dblink

I have a DB link between 2 Oracle databases, and I have a procedure which in some cases it can query the remote database.

Now the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_appdev002.htm#ADMIN12194) say that a connection is opened per session when it appears in an SP, and my question is will it establish the connection when a statement has occured or since it appears in the compiled SP it will establish it once a call has been made to the procedure?

Comment: Not until the connection is used in a particular statement.

Answer (score 0):

The dblink is used during the compilation for a first time. When you call your sp the db link will create the connection and close the connection after you exit your session.